# Syntax error on token "{", SwitchLabels expected after this token

Tags: java, switch-statement, syntax-error

i want to open new form when i select option from spinner class

i try this but i have syntax error

> Syntax error on token "{",
>   SwitchLabels expected after this
>   token

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tf);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.tfoptions,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
            switch (view.isClickable()) {       <---------------- syntax error 
                Spinner spinner2;
            case spinner2.setSelection(0):
                startActivity(new Intent(this,To.class));
                break;
            case spinner2.setSelection(1):
                startActivity(new Intent(this,out.class));
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u got the soltuion why  its coming for..

Answer (score 4):

You have tried to declare a variable before your first `case` block.  You cannot do this.  Move the variable declaration to above the `switch`.

Answer (score 2):

My friend you can't declare a variable within a switch statement:

```
View view, int pos, long id) {
     switch (view.isClickable()) {       
         Spinner spinner2;   <---------------- here is your syntax error 
         case spinner2.setSelection(0):
         startActivity(new Intent(this,To.class));
         break;
         case spinner2.setSelection(1):
         startActivity(new Intent(this,out.class));
         default:
         break;
         }
     }
```

instead you have to move above your Spinner declaration:

```
View view, int pos, long id) {
     Spinner spinner2;  // <---------------- now it's ok
     switch (view.isClickable()) {       

         case spinner2.setSelection(0):
         startActivity(new Intent(this,To.class));
         break;
         case spinner2.setSelection(1):
         startActivity(new Intent(this,out.class));
         default:
         break;
         }
     }
```

BTW, in your code you aren't initializing your Spinner..., you should also do it like:

```
Spinner spinner2 = new Spinner();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `view.isClickable()` returns a boolean, in which case you should use an `if` not a `switch`.

That said, what is `case spinner2.setSelection(0):`??

A case label can't invoke code, and it can't be dynamic.
`case` labels should be constants, either integers or enum values.

You're also declaring `Spinner spinner2;` (and declaring it in the wrong place, as Oli points out) but it's not set to anything so your `spinner2.setSelection(x)` would throw a NullPointerException even if you could get this to execute.

Comment: thanks but i cannot solve this and i do not know how to relate with this control because i start android programs from two weeks only and learning java for the first time.

Comment: `view` is an object of class `View` and `isClickable()` is a method of class `View` -- what sort of thing does isClickable() return? With a name like `is<Something>()` I imagine it returns a boolean, and a boolean is *not allowed* in those parenthesis for a `switch (x)` statement; that is, the "x" here in my comment can't be a boolean, it *must* be an `int` or an enum.